# Inserting data into database by WEB API in angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, post, webapi

I am new into angular JS and web API world. Recently facing difficulty in sending data into database through web API and angular. I am able to load JSON data from webapi. Any help will be highly appreciated.
My html:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="SubmitDataCtrl">
     <div class="container text-center" style="margin-bottom:5px">
         <div id="divTables">
             <table id="tbl_SMDetails" class="display responsive nowrap aleft" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                 <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th class="all">Name</th>
                         <th class="all">CTSID</th>
                         <th class="all">FDID</th>
                         <th class="all">Name of the Project</th>
                         <th class="all">Effort Hour</th>
                         <th class="all">Month</th>

                     </tr>
                 </thead>

                 <tbody>
                     <tr ng-repeat="showData in loadData">
                         <td>{{showData.EmpName}}</td>
                         <td>{{showData.EmpCognizantID}}</td>
                         <td>{{showData.FDID}}</td>
                         <td><input id="Text1" type="text" />{{showData.projectName}}</td>
                         <td><input id="Text1" type="text" />{{showData.effortHour}}</td>
                         <!--<td>{{date | date:'MM-dd-yyyy}}</td>-->
                         <td>{{showData.date}}</td>
                     </tr>
                 </tbody>
             </table>
         </div>

     </div>
   <div>
       <a ng-href='#SubmitData' class="btn  btn-default" ng-click='go()'>Submit</a><span></span>
       <a ng-href='#SubmitData' class="btn  btn-default" ng-click=''>Reset</a>
       
   </div> 
     </div>
```

My service page looks like:

```
var request = $http({
                        method: method_args,
                        url: myConfig.ServiceURL + url,
                        data: JSON.stringify(input_data),
                        Accept: 'application/json',
                        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
                        xhrFields: {
                            withCredentials: true
                        }
                    });
                }
```

and my controller is

```
App.controller("SubmitDataCtrl", function($scope, ajaxService) {
//login user    
ajaxService.MakeServiceCall("employee/GetTeamMember?         superVisiorCogniID=256826", "GET", "")
.then(function effortData(data)
{
  // alert(data);
  $scope.date = new Date();
  $scope.loadData = data;
  showData = $scope.loadData;
  for (var i = 0; i < showData.length; i++)
  {
      //alert(showData[i].EmpName + showData[i].EmpCognizantID + showData[i].FDID);
  }});
 
$scope.go = function()
{

   //alert('clicked');
   ajaxService.MakeServiceCall("effort/SaveTeamEfforts?hourLoadDate=08/20/2015&hourLoadByCogniID=256826&forMonth=July", "POST", Employee).then(function save() {
        var Employee =
            {
                "EmpCogniID": showData[i].EmpCognizantID,
                "FDTimeCardHour": showData[i].effortHour,
                "HourLoadDate": 08/11/2015,
                "HourLoad`enter code here`By": "256826",`enter code here`
                "ForMonth": "july"
            }
   }).success(function (Employee)
   {
       $scope.showData[i] = Employee;
   });
   alert(Employee);    }});
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? It is not hitting the web service at all?

Comment: It was not hitting the web service. I added a debug point at service call in go function but its exiting just after showing popup msg when it uncommented. The api is correct as its showing an xml page when opened in browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without knowing what the API POST call should do.

Can you confirm that the POST you are making to effort/saveTeamEfforts works by executing it using a REST tester in the browser?

if that is working, you should add an .error function to your API call and see what error is returned as dan has sugested above

L

Comment: The post method will insert values in database. Names within double quotes in var employee are column names in table.First 2 value should come from the page and last 3 was hard coded. The Api  can manually insert values when done from fiddler also when I give the full url in browser it opens an xml page. Somehow my function isnt working so its not calling the web api properly from the controller.